# Warning: Undefined array key WP PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, key, undefined

I have an error message in my Wordpress website in a plugin that i have installed.

Error message is "Warning: Undefined array key in line 163"

The line looks like that :

```
    $uip = $all_plugins["uipress/uipress.php"];
```

Can some one help me please i don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not only is this question a duplicate, there is insufficient Debugging Details to give an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip this warning use a "@" before the array variable (it's not recommended).

```
   $uip = @$all_plugins["uipress/uipress.php"];
```

Or

You can find out the place from where the array was created or generated. In that case, maybe the array key is a file name ("uipress/uipress.php"). If the file is missing then you will see this warning.

Thank you